# Adding files in Xcode 4.2 doesn't work (blue folders, files are not recognized)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In Xcode 4.2, every time I attempt to add folders of files into my project the files are not recognized. Typically, the folder is added and is displayed as a yellow folder in Xcode. But now, every time I add files to my project my folders are blue and they are not correctly recognized by Xcode.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I meet the same situation after upgrading Xcode to 4.2.
My solution is drag the whole folder into Xcode project, and then it will popup a dialog to ask you how to handle it.
Choose "Create groups for any added folders" and click finish button.
Then it should works and show a "yellow" group folder instead of a blue one.
Cheers!

Comment: It is working like a jam, very good. Just select "Copy items if needed"

Answer (score 4):

When adding a new file, in the open panel thing, there is a radio button below the outline view with the option to either `create groups` or `create folders` for any added folder. Make sure that `crate groups` is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows the folder collapsed; have you clicked the little triangle next to it to see the folder's contents?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project name and press cmd-N

Step 1 - Choose the template for your file
Step 2 - Enter class name
Step 3 - You will be asked to select the group where you want the class to be created

Once you create your class files, select the class files, right click and select (New Group from name)